# swift 3 webservice multiple time data inserted in DB using REST API

Tags: java, ios, swift, web-services, rest

I am hitting the REST API server as a client using Swift 3 programming, I have sent request once and a single response. But the problem is once i posted my data's the data's are inserted twice and getting the response based on the second insert value. 
For Example: When i posted new mail address, it inserted into Database, and it iterated again and trying to insert again and i get the response as "Email is already registered". I have tried all the methods from my client side programming.
Few have said that the server by itself restarted again after 40 sec, i'm not sure if that is the case how to overcome this problem.

CODE IN SWIFT 3 CLIENT:(iOS)

```
func getMailAddress(mailID: String) {
        let username = "admin"
        let password = "admin"
        let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let getUrl = URL(string: "http://localhost/rest/merchantsignup/mailExists/\(mailID)")
        var request = URLRequest(url: getUrl!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue(base64LoginString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
        urlConnection?.start()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                do {
                    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                    print("myJSON:\(myJSON)")
                } catch let err as NSError {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        }
```

CODE IN JAVA REST WEBSERVICES:

```
@GET
    @Path("/mailExists/{emailId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public RestResMessagesVO mailExists(@PathParam("emailId")String emailId){   
        System.out.println(emailId);
         MerchantRegistrationDAO mcdao = new MerchantRegistrationDAO();
         RestResMessagesVO resObj = new RestResMessagesVO();
         resObj.setMessage(mcdao.ismcEmailorPhoneExists("emailAddress",emailId.trim()));
         return resObj; 
    }
```

Comment: please show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to establish a connection with basic authentication, but actual problem here, while your requesting your server it get hitted twice is 
1. you established your connection using request so, by that time it hitted the server once.
2. Then you created an object for NSURLConnection, and you started the connection, by that it hits the server second time.
       Because of this only you hit your server twice, and get the response based on the second server hit.

Solution: Try this to overcome your Problem:

```
 let username = "admin"
 let password = "admin"
 let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
 let loginData: NSData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
 let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
 let getUrl = URL(string: "Your URL String")
 var request = URLRequest(url: getUrl!)
 request.httpMethod = "GET"
 request.setValue(base64LoginString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) 
 { (data, response, error) in
 if error != nil 
 {
 print(error!)
 } 
 else 
 {
 do {
 let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
    print("YOUR RESPONSE: \(JSON)")

    } 
 catch let err as NSError 
 {
 print(err)
 }
 }
 }
 task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

probably that's because you are calling

```
urlConnection?.start()
```

and

```
task.resume()
```

Comment: but i used urlConnection?.start() for establishing the connection with the server and task.resume() is to serialize JSON response